# Setting Different error bar colors in bar plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Following [Setting Different Bar color in matplotlib Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973404/settting-different-bar-color-in-matplotlib-python/18973430#18973430)

I would like to change the error bar colors. I have figured out a way after a number of attempts:

```
a = plt.gca()
b = a.bar(range(4), [2]*4, yerr=range(4))
c = a.get_children()[8]
c.set_color(['r','r','b','r'])
```

Is there any better way? Certainly `a.get_children()[8]` is not a general solution at all.

[image]

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you just want to set them to a single color, use the `error_kw` kwarg (expected to be a dict of keyword arguments that's passed on to `ax.errorbar`).

Also, just so you know, you can pass a sequence of facecolors directly to `bar`, though this won't change the errorbar color.

As a quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(range(4), [2] * 4, yerr=range(1, 5), alpha=0.5,
       color=['red', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan', 'magenta'],
       error_kw=dict(ecolor='gray', lw=2, capsize=5, capthick=2))
ax.margins(0.05)

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, if you want the errorbars to be different colors, you'll either need to plot them individually or modify them afterwards.

If you use the latter option, the capline colors actually can't be changed individually (note that they're not changed in @falsetru's example either).  For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan', 'magenta']

container = ax.bar(range(4), [2] * 4, yerr=range(1, 5), alpha=0.5, color=colors,
       error_kw=dict(lw=2, capsize=5, capthick=2))
ax.margins(0.05)

connector, caplines, (vertical_lines,) = container.errorbar.lines
vertical_lines.set_color(colors)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The `caplines` object in the answer above is a tuple of two `Line2D`s: One line for all of the top caps, and one line for all of the bottom caps.  There's not way to change the colors of the caps individually (it's easy to set them all to the same color) without removing that artist and creating a `LineCollection` in its place.

Therefore, you're better off just plotting the errorbars individually in this case.

E.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, height, error = range(4), [2] * 4, range(1,5)
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan', 'magenta']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, height, alpha=0.5, color=colors)
ax.margins(0.05)

for pos, y, err, color in zip(x, height, error, colors):
    ax.errorbar(pos + 0.4, y, err, lw=2, capsize=5, capthick=2, color=color)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: very very helpful, this info should exist in official tutorial.

Comment: For some unclear reason, `vertical_lines.set_color(colors)` has no effect on my plots.

Answer (score 3):

Not a general solution neither, but here it is.

```
a = plt.gca()
b = a.bar(range(4), [2]*4, yerr=range(4))
c = b.errorbar.lines[2][b.errorbar.has_xerr] # <----
c.set_color(['r', 'r', 'b', 'r'])


# from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
# next(i
#      for i, x in enumerate(b.errorbar.lines)
#      if x and any(isinstance(y, LineCollection) for y in x)) == 2
```