# matplotlib: change line color of error bar component in boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot, errorbar

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912197/settting-different-error-bar-colors-in-bar-plot-in-matplotlib) related, older question. Sadly. the `error_kw` does not exist anymore (using matplotlib version 1.5.0). The `capprops` dictionary indeed only works on the cap.

I would like to change the line that extends from the box to the cap. Default is dashed blue, as seen below. I tried all the documented format dicts, but none of them is responsible for this line.

[image: example boxplot with indication of what I would like to change]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the "whiskers" and are returned by `boxplot`. Iterate over them and set the style accordingly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# fake up some data
spread = np.random.rand(50) * 100
center = np.ones(25) * 50
flier_high = np.random.rand(10) * 100 + 100
flier_low = np.random.rand(10) * -100
data = np.concatenate((spread, center, flier_high, flier_low), 0)

plt.figure()
bp = plt.boxplot(data, 1)

for whisker in bp['whiskers']:
    whisker.set(color='#ff0000',lw=2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: wow, I completely missed that one. thanks for the quick answer, I cannot even accept it yet (:

Comment: No worries. You can set the cap styles to match by iterating over `bp['caps']`, by the way.

Comment: Nice answer. You can even do it without the explicit loop: `plt.setp(bp['whiskers'], color='#ff0000', lw=2)`