# Border on errorbars in matplotlib/python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for a way to set a black border on the errorbars in my plot,

The following code:

```
ax.errorbar(x, y, yerr, fmt='o', label='label',color="#8da0cb",capthick=2, elinewidth=2,zorder=10)
```

produces:

[image: errorbar]

I find it more aesthetically pleasing if there was a black border around the errorbar like there is on the marker.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a great solution, but you could get close by plotting the errorbars again behind your original ones, with a wider line and cap thinkness, and setting the colour of those ones to black. We can make use of the `zorder` kwarg to put them behind the others.

Heres a MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fake data
x=np.arange(0,5,1)
y=np.ones(x.shape)
yerr = np.ones(x.shape)/4.

# Create figure
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

# Set some limits
ax.set_xlim(-1,5)
ax.set_ylim(-2,4)

# Plot errorbars with the line color you want
ax.errorbar(x,y,yerr, fmt='o',color='r',capthick=2,elinewidth=2,capsize=3,zorder=10)

# Plot black errorbars behind (lower zorder) with a wider line and cap thinkness
ax.errorbar(x,y,yerr, fmt='o',color='k',capthick=4,elinewidth=4,capsize=4,zorder=5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Again, not a perfect solution, but at least it allows you to include it in the legend. This time, rather than plot the errorbars twice, we will use the [`matplotlib.patheffects`](http://matplotlib.org/users/patheffects_guide.html) module to add a [`Stroke`](http://matplotlib.org/users/patheffects_guide.html#making-an-artist-stand-out) to the errorbars.

`errorbar` returns several `Line2D` and `LineCollection` objects, so we need to apply the stroke to each of the relevant ones.

```
import matplotlib.patheffects as path_effects

e = ax.errorbar(x,y,yerr, fmt='o',color='r',capthick=2,elinewidth=2, label='path effects')

e[1][0].set_path_effects([path_effects.Stroke(linewidth=4, foreground='black'),
                          path_effects.Normal()])
e[1][1].set_path_effects([path_effects.Stroke(linewidth=4, foreground='black'),
                          path_effects.Normal()])
e[2][0].set_path_effects([path_effects.Stroke(linewidth=4, foreground='black'),
                          path_effects.Normal()])

ax.legend(loc=0)
```

[image]

Comment: I would also add 'capsize = x' to make the sides of the caps also appear in black

Comment: Any idea how one would go by so that it also appears in the legend ?

Comment: Good idea re: `capsize`. No idea about the legend, sorry

Comment: @AnthonyLethuillier OK, So I do have an idea - we can use `patheffects`. I've edited the answer. Its still not perfect, but might give you something to play with.

Comment: That's great, I use it for now, I posted an issue on Gihub we will see what comes of it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see from the information provided in the [webpage of pyplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar) I do not see a valid `kwargs` that exists for what you are asking.

There exists `mfc, mec, ms` and `mew` which are `markerfacecolor, markeredgecolor, markersize` and `markeredgewith`. It can probably be [asked in GitHub](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib) so that people take this into consideration and add it in the next version of matplotlib.

Also taking a look at [the answer for this question asked in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912197/settting-different-error-bar-colors-in-bar-plot-in-matplotlib), I don't believe it can be done.