# White errorbars with black borders in a Pandas bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I was wondering if it possible to achieve so that error bars are made white with a black border (in a Pandas bar plot)?

I am trying to achieve what is mentioned in the accepted answer in this post ([Border on errorbars in matplotlib/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173774/border-on-errorbars-in-matplotlib-python?lq=1)), however I am wondering if it is possible to implement this for a Pandas plot?

The relevant Pandas plot:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

txt = u'''Category    COLUMN1         COLUMN2     COLUMN3    
A          0.5               3          Cat1   
B          0.3               5          Cat1 
C          0.7               4          Cat1
A          0.4               3          Cat2
B          0.8               5          Cat2
C          0.3               4          Cat2
'''

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+")

order = ['Cat2', 'Cat1']
suborder = list("BAC")

df2 = pd.pivot_table(df,index='COLUMN3',columns='Category',values='COLUMN2').loc[order]
df2 = df2[suborder]
df2.plot(kind='bar', 
         yerr=pd.pivot_table(df,
                             index='COLUMN3',
                             columns='Category',values='COLUMN1')
                .reindex(df2.index)
                .reindex(df2.columns, axis=1), capsize=4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically use the same principle as shown in the answer you link to, with some slight modifications as you are using `pandas` rather than pure `matplotlib`. The idea is the same, to plot the graph twice, and on the second time use slightly thicker errorbars and set the zorder lower which we can do using a dictionary of kwargs - `error_kw` . In addition, make sure to pass the `ax=` argument too in order to make sure the plots appear on the same figure and set `legend=False` on the second plot to avoid repeating legend entries.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df2.plot(kind='bar', 
         yerr=pd.pivot_table(df,
                             index='COLUMN3',
                             columns='Category',values='COLUMN1')
                .reindex(df2.index)
                .reindex(df2.columns, axis=1), ax=ax,
                error_kw=dict(ecolor='white', capthick=2,elinewidth=2,capsize=3,zorder=10))


df2.plot(kind='bar', 
         yerr=pd.pivot_table(df,
                             index='COLUMN3',
                             columns='Category',values='COLUMN1')
                .reindex(df2.index)
                .reindex(df2.columns, axis=1), ax=ax, legend=False,
                error_kw=dict(ecolor='black',capthick=4,elinewidth=4,capsize=4,zorder=5))
```

[image]