# plt.errorbar ValueError when specify color as list

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am currently trying to plot errorbars for a scatterplot, but if I try to specify the color the program crashes with an `ValueError`.
This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
yerr = [0.1, 0.01, 0.5, 0.3]
color = ([0.9,0.1,0.2],
         '#5BC433',
         '#5BC433',
         'k')

plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=yerr, fmt=".", color=color)
plt.show()
```

It results in the following error: `ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: ([0.9,0.1,0.2], '#5BC433, '#5BC433', 'k')`

I can circumvent the problem by doing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
yerr = [0.1, 0.01, 0.5, 0.3]
color = ([0.9,0.1,0.2],
         '#5BC433',
         '#5BC433',
         'k')


for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.errorbar(x[i], y[i], yerr=yerr[i], fmt=".", color=color[i])
plt.show()
```

This seems overly complicated...
Furthermore, my real data contains thousands of points so it takes very long doing it like this.

Can somebody point out what I am doing wrong in my first code example?

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks alot!

Comment: Could you loop over the colors and plot once per color? Assuming, that you have only few colors to plot and each color had many errorbars.

Comment: @nhaus: this [already has an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21915157/2375855). Your "complicated" way is one of the ways to do it. Possibly faster is to plot everything in a single color and then only `set_color` in the loop (as shown in the linked answer).