# Matplotlib errorbar bug with capsize + ecolor?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When using `matplotlib` version `3.4.2` the following fails with "ValueError: ['r', 'g', 'b'] is not a valid value for color":

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3]
yerr = [.1,.2,.3]

plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=yerr, fmt='.', capsize=10, ecolor=['r', 'g', 'b'])
plt.show(block=True)
```

This does NOT happen when the `capsize=10` argument is removed, in that case everything works fine. Is this a bug? Can I circumvent it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912197/setting-different-error-bar-colors-in-bar-plot-in-matplotlib