# Matplotlib, legends are not appearing in the histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, legend

to describe my problem i am providing you with small dataset as an example: so imagine following dataset:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 'val':[1,5,3,4,5,3]} )
```

I am creating simple histogam with following code:

```
def plot_bar_x():
    index = np.arange(len(df['name']))
    plt.bar(index, df['val'])
    plt.legend(list(df['name'].unique()))
    plt.xticks(index, df['name'], fontsize=10, rotation=30)
    plt.show()
plot_bar_x()
```

But it gives me following plot: 
[image]

Although I have 3 unique names but i see only 'a' label, however i used this line: plt.legend(list(df['name'].unique()))
the other issue is that all the bars are in the same color, is there a way to get different colors for unique labels without defining colors beforehand manually?

desired output is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only plot once on one series, that's why `plt` only picks one label for legend. If you don't have a lot of names, try:

```
def plot_bar_x():
    index = np.arange(len(df['name']))
    plt.figure()
    for name in df.name.unique():
        tmp_df = df[df.name == name]
        plt.bar(tmp_df.index, tmp_df.val, label=name)
    plt.xticks(index, df['name'], fontsize=10, rotation=30)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

There must be some clever way to solve your problem, but it's over my head now.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly plot the DataFrame using `df.plot()` and then pass the colors of each bar using some predefined dictionary. Then you can create legends using `mpatches.Patch` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29640501/4932316). You can use `seaborn` to have the grayish background with grids. The colors can be generated depending on the number of unique items in the DataFrame.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(123)
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 'val':[1,5,3,4,5,3]} )
col_dict = {k:np.random.rand(3,) for k in df['name'].unique()}

ax = df.plot.bar(x='name', y='val', color=[col_dict[i] for i in df['name']])
labels = [mpatches.Patch(color=v, label=k) for k,v in col_dict.items()]
plt.legend(handles=labels, loc='best')    
plt.show()
```

[image]