# How to label colored bars on matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm trying to plot a bar graph in which certain bars need to be highlighted. How do I include a legend that explains what the colored bars are?

Below is my code. I want the legend to indicate that "Relevant bars" are blue (not gray, as it says at the moment).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = range(1,6)
labels = ['a','b','c','d','e']
relevant_bars = ['b','e']

bars = plt.bar(data, data, color='gray')

for i in range(len(bars)):
    if labels[i] in relevant_bars:
        bars[i].set_color('blue')

plt.xticks(pos, labels)
plt.legend(['Relevant bars']);
```

[image]

Comment: See also [Custom legend in Pandas bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639973/custom-legend-in-pandas-bar-plot-matplotlib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
   plt.legend(['Relevant bars']);
```

to

```
    legend_elements = [Line2D([0], [0], color='b', lw=4, label='Relevant bars')]
    plt.legend(handles=legend_elements);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take the rectangle patch of the legend and set its color:

```
legend = plt.legend(['Relevant bars'])
legend.get_patches()[0].set_color('b')
```