# Color specific bars in matplot lib according to x label

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I am using matplotlib to plot a bar graph like so:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = ('sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3')
y = (-1, 0, 1)
plt.bar(x,y)
```

Now I want to loop through the graph definition, generating a new graph for every item in x, and coloring the respective x bar differently to emphasize it in each graph.  This would produce a graph with the bar for 'sample1' in red (all other bars black), and another graph with 'sample2' in red (all other bars black), etc.

`color` can be set as an argument to `plt.bar()`, but it appears to take a list.  I'm unsure how to take advantage of this argument in a way that allows the color list to change with every loop through the graph definition.

Comment: the code above produces a TypeError ... is it your actual code?

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973404/setting-different-bar-color-in-matplotlib-python answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array, all the same color. Then, for each iteration, copy that array to a temporary array and change the respective entry in that temporary array to the emphasis color. Something like this:

```
colors = ['k','k','k']
for i in range(3):
    tempcolors = list(colors)
    tempcolors[i] = 'r'
    plt.figure()
    plt.bar(x,y,color=tempcolors)
```

Comment: Lists are mutable, you are going to end up with an all-red list by the end of this loop.

Comment: Fixed so that the list is copied.

Comment: Changing color list elements according to an incrementing loop is a good idea.  Thanks FTA.