# Python: How to compare dictionary & set and then plot?

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, plot

I have a set:

```
K = {'A', 'E', 'R', 'T'}
```

and a dictionary called:

```
Dic = {'A': 25, 'C': 35, 'E': 10, 'R': 7, 'S': 9, 'T': 11}
```

I know to plot the dictionary `Dic` by

```
X = np.arange(len(Dic))
plt.bar(X,Dic.values(),width=0.5)
plt.xticks(X,list(Dic.keys()))
```

[image]

Now I want to change the colours of the bar `'A', 'E' , 'R', 'T'` in the graph. Simply like `Dic` intersection `K`.

But, I don't know how to compare the set items with the dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

```
K.intersection(Dic)
```

That will get you the keys that are in both.

The color changing part of your question is answered here:

[Setting Different Bar color in matplotlib Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973404/setting-different-bar-color-in-matplotlib-python)

```
Dic = {'A': 25, 'C': 35, 'E': 10, 'R': 7, 'S': 9, 'T': 11}
K = {'A', 'E', 'R', 'T'}
values = [Dic[key] for key in sorted(Dic)]
intersection = K.intersection(Dic)
X = range(len(Dic))


bar_graph = plt.bar(X, values,width=0.5)
print intersection, 'inter'
for i, thing in enumerate(sorted(Dic)):
    if thing in intersection:
        bar_graph[i].set_color('r')
plt.xticks(X,sorted(Dic.keys()))
plt.show()
```

You have to do some sorting to make sure the keys are in the same place as plotted.  Python dictionaries do not keep the keys in any sorted order.

Comment: you can also do "shared_elements = K & set(Dic.keys())" to key the keys

Comment: @Garrett . I dint down voted it. The link which you gave provides solution on the basis of List. How to do it for set  ?

Comment: did it work for you?  if so, you can select it as an answer

Comment: No it dint worked. Any help to get plot colour will be appreciable