# Bargraph condition color option in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

How can I modify the below code to colour age group 0-20 as orange and 60 above as red and Rest as yellow?

Below is the code:

```
Import matplotlib. pyplot as plt
dataset. Plot(Kind='bar', x='Patient_Age_Grp',y='Claim_amount', color='red') 
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('claimed amount') 
plt.show()
```

Regard
Newbee

Comment: You will get your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973404/setting-different-bar-color-in-matplotlib-python

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use matplotlib's direct function rather than using any other library's implementation of it like Pandas, as sometimes they don't function right (in case of twinx() for date axis for example). So I'd write your code like the following:

```
Import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(dataset['Patient_Age_Grp'], dataset['Claim_amount'], 
       color = ['orange' if 20=>i>=0 else 'red' if i>=60 else 'yellow' for i in dataset['Patient_Age_Grp']]
       )
ax.set_xlabel('Age')
ax.set_ylabel('claimed amount') 
plt.show()
```

(P.S. Idk if those spaces in your code were because of your phone's autocorrection or not, just be wary of it)