# How to set colors of specific bars in matplotlib object oriented way?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, jupyter

Currently there is **no easy way to set specific colors for specific bars** in matplotlib if you are using the **object oriented method**.

This leads to my second question which is **what is the best way to plot in matplotlib (the pyplot one or the oop one)?**

One hack I found:

```py
  heights = x
  labels = y

  colors = ["dimgrey" for x in labels]
  if np.isin(true_val, labels):
    index = np.argmax(labels == true_val)
    colors[index] = "green"

  ax[3].bar(labels, heights, color=colors)
```

Pyplot way:

```py
barlist=plt.bar([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4])
barlist[0].set_color('r')
```

Similar Questions:

- [Setting Different Bar color in matplotlib Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973404/setting-different-bar-color-in-matplotlib-python)

Answer (score 0):

Assign the the barcontainer returned from `ax[1].bar(labels, heights, color="dimgrey")` to a `barlist` and manipulate the colors using `barlist`.

```py
heights = x
labels = y

barlist = ax[1].bar(labels, heights, color="dimgrey")

barlist[0].set_color('green')
```