# How do I change the colour of 1 specific bar in a bar chart using Python- IDE Jupiter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is currently this- Using a date set I have created!

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import os

    desired_width=420
    pd.set_option('display.width', desired_width)
    np.set_printoptions(linewidth=desired_width)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns',6)

    Data = pd.read_csv("/Volumes/DYLAN USB/Excel/DataSheets/Data Passing Feb EPL 202021.csv",index_col=0)
```

print(Data.head(20))

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    Data = Data.sort_values('Total Pass Completion %', ascending=False)
    ax.bar(Data.Team, Data['Total Pass Completion %'])
    ax.set_xticklabels (Data.Team, rotation=90, horizontalalignment = 'right', fontsize = '12')

   ax.set_title ('League Ranking and Points- EPL 2020/21 February', fontsize =22)
   ax.set_ylabel ('Pass Completition %')
   ax.set_xlabel ('Team Name')
```

Comment: Can you post some reproducible data please?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973404/setting-different-bar-color-in-matplotlib-python

Comment: I think you can use ax.get_children()[i].set_color('r'), r is for red

Comment: @WilliamGoodwin I may sound stupid but how can I make this work with my data set. I am very new to programming so slightly lost.

Comment: @WilliamGoodwin My data is from a file so how can I reference this

Comment: You can just give a small sample, maybe 5-10 rows. I usually just type it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide some sample data if you want people to easily solve your question. I created some data below. You can index the bar objects `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle` and set them to the color you want

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

Data = pd.DataFrame({'Total Pass Completion %': [100, 30, 8, 4], 'Team': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
Data = Data.sort_values('Total Pass Completion %', ascending=False)
ax.bar(Data.Team, Data['Total Pass Completion %'])
ax.set_xticklabels (Data.Team, rotation=90, horizontalalignment = 'right', fontsize = '12')

ax.set_title ('League Ranking and Points- EPL 2020/21 February', fontsize =22)
ax.set_ylabel ('Pass Completition %')
ax.set_xlabel ('Team Name')


ax.get_children()[1].set_color('r')
```