# How to plot bar chart with python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, visualization

I want to visualize a bar plot with 2 classes. Class=0 its color blue and class=1 its color red.

```
#here its my code
x = ['0','1']
real = df[df['fake'] == 0].count()
fake = df[df['fake'] == 1].count()
plt.bar(x, real, color='blue')
plt.bar(x, fake, color='red')
plt.title("Class Fake & Real")
plt.show()
```

**Error code :**
**ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x = ['0', '1']
real, fake = 5, 10
plt.bar(x[0], real, color='blue')
plt.bar(x[1], fake, color='red')
plt.title("Class Fake & Real")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Your error may comes from wrong types of `real` and `fake`. BTW, for configuring different colors for bars, there is a better [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973404/setting-different-bar-color-in-matplotlib-python).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `matplotlib`'s bar plot to plot the counts for each class, you can you `seaborn`'s `countplot`.

```
plt.figure(figsize = (7,5))
sns.countplot(x = "fake", data = df, palette=["blue","red"])
plt.show()
```

Output -

[image]